# jquery plugins conflicting

Tags: jquery, web

I'm trying to put both a text ticker and an image magnifier into a webpage declaring them like so

```
<script type='text/javascript' src='http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.6.4/jquery.min.js?ver=1.4.2'></script>
          <script type="text/javascript" src="scripts/jquery.ticker.js" ></script>
          <script type="text/javascript" src="scripts/jquery.magnifier.js"></script>
```

I have no idea why when I use the magnifier the text ticker will not show, as soon as I take I out it comes back again.

Comment: May be they don't like each other? Do you see any error in the console?

Comment: Something is strange here: jquery/1.6.4/jquery.min.js?ver=1.4.2'   no?

Comment: Nothing inherently wrong with using multiple jquery plugins. Would need to see the errors or a JSfiddle with external links to your plugins.

Comment: I am sure it is not conflicting, can you show some more code so that i can understand the problem

Comment: I'm using http://www.jquerynewsticker.com for the ticker and magnifier this http://www.dynamicdrive.com/dynamicindex4/imagemagnify.htm
This is what i get in my console: http://snag.gy/uYQ4I.jpg

Comment: Does this give you a 404 when you go to it in your browser? http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.6.4/jquery.min.js?ver=1.4.2 if you're script includes are as-is above, that error should not be happening. That error is not caused by a plugin conflict.

Comment: Do you have the line that loads jQuery before line 22 in index.php?

Comment: That link sends me to an obfuscated and compressed jQuery v1.6.4

Comment: Then your page has more script includes than you included above. You are most likely including jQuery twice.

Comment: @KevinB That wouldn't give the "$ is not a function" error. My guess is that the scripts are being loaded in wrong order.

Comment: Those above are the only script files I've included how could I be adding more in?

Comment: @JoshNaylor The error message says that you have some jQuery code on line 22 of index.php. Again, do you load jQuery before or after line 22?

Comment: I load all the above on lines 7,8,9 and this below on 17-24
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function(){ 
         
 $('#js-news').ticker({
            titleText: 'Join Us'
            });
});
</script>

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For some reason the magnifier plugin has this line near the start:

```
jQuery.noConflict()
```

It makes the `$` shortcut to not work anymore. Remove that line and it should work.

Comment: Thanks so much!! Can't believe it was that.